# Issues with rotating segmented Picker

Tags: swiftui

I am essentially working with this [template](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-segmented-control-and-read-values-from-it).

```
@State  var Scenario = 0

Picker(selection: $Scenario, label: Text("")) {
            Text("1").tag(0)
            Text("2").tag(1)
            Text("3").tag(2)
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
```

**I would like the text to be also rotated.**

I've tried all ways I could think of rotating them, and exhausted Google.
Another issue is that the `frame` remains in the *original unrotated* horizontal *position*. Which isn't good for fitting it in.

Comment: "not to use SegmentedPickerStyle directly" that just means, don't say something like `VStack { SegmentedPickerStyle() }`. Just use it inside `pickerStyle`, like what you're doing currently.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove it from the Question because it's tangential and trivial.